# RSS feed into Excel

Tags: excel, rss, feed

I try to get an RSS feed into excel.
I subscribed to a feed. When opening the feed in Internet Explorer, I can see around 400 items. But when I use the excel import via xml only a small part of it gets imported (the most recent one). 
How is it possible to get all data?

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for learn about Stack Overflow. Which RSS you're using and how you're importing the rss? [edit] your question.

Comment: What do you mean which RSS? The exact webside providing the feed?
I want to import it via xml. 
That means: Excel-> Developer-> Source-> open Link

Sorry, I am completely new with RSS feeds.

Comment: DiBiDa, exactly, I'm talking about the exact webside providing the feed. browsing a little I found [this tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/excelrssfeeds.html) or check this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtpWHcUja1w). However, I encourage you to investigate more and [edit] your question with the resuls you got so far. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. But that is exactly the way I tried.
The download shoudl be from https://rtdata.dtcc.com/gtr/rss.do
They provide 4 RSS feeds. I can see all feed items (around 400 a day) in my internt explorer. When creating a feed into excel, only the most recent ones (maybe 10) are downloaded.